# ConstantScoreQuery in elasticsearch

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

I'm not sure how ConstantScoreQuery works regarding performance in Elasticsearch 1.4 (I don't think much changed between 1.0 and 2.0 regarding this)

A simple query has to calculate score so if you do a query like this :

```
{ 
  "constant_score":
    "match": {"field":"text"}
}
```

it's obviously faster than without constant_score.

Now if you are doing a boolQuery, is there a difference between wrapping the boolQuery with constant_score or wrapping every must/should/must_not clause ?
exemples :

```
{
 "constant_score": {
  "bool":{
    "must": [
        {"match": {"field1": "text1"}},
        {"match": {"field2": "text2"}}
    ]
  }
 }
}
```

versus

```
{
  "bool":{
    "must": [
        {"constant_score": {"match": {"field1": "text1"}}},
        {"constant_score": {"match": {"field2": "text2"}}}
    ]
  }
}
```

Another one, when you do a boolFilter with 2 `"should"` cases, by default `"minimum_should_match"` is set to 1 and if the first tested case is OK it doesn't bother to check the other.

With queries, the score is important so each `"should"` is tested and adds up to the score of the hit. Is there a way with constant_score wrapping a bool query to make it a simple "OR" bool like the above filter ? By this I mean not checking every `"should"` on each document.

Thanks for your insights :)

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this on a local elasticsearch (1.4.4)

It turns out if you wrap a constant_score around a bool query with shoulds it doesn't behave like a boolFilter, it returns every document.
So the minimum should match is mandatory.

About using constant_score on the bool query or on each part, the return is the same, every result has the same score but I still don't know if it was computed before and then set to a constant one...